# How to add aws new elb in autoscaling group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, autoscaling

Aws has introduce a new elb called  alb, this page explain how to add the alb in an auto scaling group, but in the aws console there is no way to do that. 
someone know to associate alb with auto scaling?

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/target-group-register-targets.html

> If your load balancer is attached to an Auto Scaling group and the group 
>   scales out, the targets added to the Auto Scaling group are
>   automatically registered with the target group configured for the Auto
>   Scaling group. If you detach the load balancer from the Auto Scaling
>   group, the targets in the Auto Scaling group are automatically
>   deregistered from the target group.

Comment: Where did you try to add the ALB to the autoscaling group?  Via the ALB page or the Autoscaling group page?

Comment: via the the autoscaling group page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot integrate alb in auto scaling group, but you can integrate target group (which has targets [ECS or EC2]).

---

see the how to in this answer [integrate target group in auto scaling group](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38964039/2607613)