# how to auto scale AWS target group?

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling

In AWS console how to insert ec2 instance from auto scaling group into a target group?

I need this to auto scale my application load balancer.

Comment: Have you seen this: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-elasticloadbalancingv2-targetgroup.html

Comment: this is an AWS ELB 101 question, you need to review the excellent documentation

Comment: @Vorsprung What do you mean by `AWS ELB 101`? Can you provide a link?

Comment: @zatziky https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/what-is-amazon-ec2-auto-scaling.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use aws-cli [attach-load-balancer-target-groups](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/autoscaling/attach-load-balancer-target-groups.html#synopsis)
aws auto scaling group ui will update after that.